# change android:enabled="true" programmatically

Tags: android

At first start, my app set preferences to "true" about checkboxpreference. Now I need to set this value (android:enabled="true") or false programmatically. Any idea?

```
protected void checkLicense(){
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        if (manager.checkSignatures("core.package.name", "key.package.name")
            == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
            //full version
            isEnabled = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "pro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "free", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isEnabled = false;




<CheckBoxPreference
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:title="Now"
                        android:defaultValue="false"
                        android:key="keep" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Enabling CheckBox**

```
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("checkbox-preference-key").setEnabled(true); //Enabling
```

---

**Disabling CheckBox**

```
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("checkbox-preference-key").setEnabled(false);//Disabling
```

Comment: I don't need enable/disable all checkboxpreferences. I need enable/disable ONLY android:enabled

Comment: `android:enable="true"` inside that only means checkbox is enable. To enable/disable `android:enable="true"`, you need to enable/disable complete **Checkbox**  inside of your _Preference-Screen_

Comment: Understood, but... How I create a getPreferenceScreen() method?

Comment: `getPreferenceScreen()` **is inbuilt method under API 11 - which gives the default preference of your Applications**.

Comment: mhmhm...I need use it also < api 11 which is best way? thanks!